# Preview canción de Spotify en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando obtener un preview de canciones de 30 segundos para mi app pero, lo que obtengo es la canción entera, dada la condición de la API de spotify, no puedo establecer un audio player ya que las canciones las obtengo desde otro webservice.

Lo que tengo es que cada vez que el usuario pulsa sobre una canción (están en un ListView), le lleva a otro fragment donde se ven todos los detalles de la canción, pero suena toda la canción, cosa que no quiero, solo quiero que suenen 30 segundos de esa canción, como el estribillo o algo así, si alguien sabe como hacerlo, se lo agradezco.

Dejo la parte del código donde obtengo toda la canción :

```
mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:43it4kot08akLzFIEMhXNN", 0, 0);
```

De esta forma obtengo la canción directamente en el fragment y dentro de mi aplicación sin que salga de ahí, he intentado cambiando "track" por "audio-analysis" pero, no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tenias una posible solución
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383808/android-how-can-play-song-for-30-seconds-only-in-mediaplayer

```
CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
};

cntr_aCounter.start();
```